# Mobile backbutton in AngularJS with Cordova/PhoneGap not working

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing my first AngularJS Mobile App for Android with Cordova/PhoneGap. I have added below code inside my script file but I am unable to capture the backbutton event. Here is what I have in my scripts.js:

```
  var app = angular.module('QFA', []);

  app.controller('QFAinit', function( $scope, $window ) {

          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);

          function onDeviceReady() {

            $window.alert("Device Ready-1");
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
            $window.alert("Device Ready-2");

            function onBackKeyDown() {
              $window.alert("Inside onBackKeyDown1");
            }
         }
  });
```

And I am calling this as follows:

```
  <body ng-controller="QFAinit">
```

When I run the App I do get "Device Ready-1" and "Device Ready-2" alerts. which means deviceready event is getting fired properly and an attempt on backbutton has also been made. However when I press backbutton nothing happens as desired and instead the default behavior is performed, i.e. the App exits.

On the other hand if I replace onBackKeyDown with onBackKeyDown() on eventlistener command then I get the "Inside onBackKeyDown1" alert when the App is loaded, just immediately after the above mentioned two alerts. But once the App is loaded then backbutton functionality is not there.

How can I make this work?

### Update

I have realized that I need to include cordova.js to trap backbutton. Once I add that, the back button does get trapped. However, as a result of that I get a broken App as shown below:

[image]

I have also tried changing versions of jQuery from 2.1 to 1.11, 1.10 and 1.4.5 but that doesn't have any impact. In fact even if I remove jQuery I still get the broken interface.

Comment: Are the brackets always showing or only when you push the back button? There are errors in your console, I would suggest you will install Eclipse to read from logcat so you can know what is going wrong in your application.

Comment: They always show, if I add cordova.js. They go away when cordova.js is removed.
Eclipse.....Another learning exercise :-(

Answer (score 0):

If I remind correctly, is the alert box on mobile devices asynchronous. It is possible that the app has not the time to show the alert box because it is already closing. If you do a `console.log` can you read it in Eclipse logcat? Or if you do a prevent default should it prevent from closing the app:

```
 function onBackKeyDown(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $window.alert("Inside onBackKeyDown1");
 }
```

Comment: Alert must stop everything that is running. It used to work with the previous version of my App that was built with PhoneGap+JQueryMobile. I am redeveloping the same App in AngularJS with PhoneGap and its not working here. 

I think preventDefault is not required anymore with latest Cordova. But I tried that also without any success.

Sorry I am not using Eclipse and work on Command Line. The behavior is same in Mobile as well as Ripple Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what finally worked for me, putting all this in  section. Though it would work in Body as well. Not is Controller anymore.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>        

  <script>
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);

     function onDeviceReady() {

       document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, true);

     }

     function onBackKeyDown() {
        alert('Back Button Pressed');
        resp = confirm("If you use Home key to exit, the App will remain active. Still want to Quit?");
        if (resp === true) {
          navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
     }
   </script>

  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```